# What will be the output of following Java program? And why I am getting error

Tags: java

I am getting error message if i execute the following program. It says `o` cannot be resolved to a variable.

```
public class Test {

    /**
* @param args
*/
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try{
            int o[] = new int[2];
            o[3]=23;
            o[1]=33;
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(o[1]); //THis line shows the error.
    }

}
```

Why I am i getting in the line   `System.out.println(o[1]);` ?

Comment: Look at your original error, as printed by your `catch` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `scope` of your int o is limited to the `try-catch` block. Move it outside the `try-catch` block to access it in the `sysout()`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     /* Moved Outside */
     int o[] = new int[4];

        try{
            o[3] = 23;
            o[1] = 33;
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        /* o will be visible now */
        System.out.println(o[1]);
    }
```

Also, in order for `o[3] = 23;` to be executed, you will have to increase the array size to a minimum of 4.

Answer (score 1):

First oft all you initialize o inside the try-block, so o is not visible outside of it. Changing this and calling o[3] will give an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds as o has only size of 2.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the scope. since you define o in the try block, the compiler doesn't know o outside of the try/catch.
To Solve the Problem either put the print in a finally block or initialize o before the try block.

read more about variable scope here:
http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0020__Language/VariableScope.htm